# Is there a Scala pattern for collecting error messages from a sequence of independent computations?

Tags: scala, monads, for-comprehension

Say I have a series of independent computations that need to be combined at the end:

```
def makeSauce():  Try[Sauce]  = Success(Sauce("marinara"))
def makeCrust():  Try[Crust]  = Failure(new RuntimeException("stale bread"))
def makeCheese(): Try[Cheese] = Failure(new IllegalArgumentException("moldy cheese"))

for {
  sauce  <- makeSauce()
  crust  <- makeCrust()
  cheese <- makeCheese()
} yield {
  Pizza(sauce, crust, cheese)
}
```

But if any of my computations fail, I want a comprehensive error message describing *all* of the failures, not just the first. The above code doesn't do what I want; it only shows me the first failure (`"stale bread"`). Instead, it should throw a super-error message combining both of the others, which could be a sequence of exception objects, sequence of string error messages, or even just one giant concatenated string.

Alternatively, instead of throwing the exception, it could be composed into a top-level `Failure` object:

```
(for {
  sauce  <- makeSauce()
  crust  <- makeCrust()
  cheese <- makeCheese()
} yield (sauce, crust, cheese)) match {
  case Success((sauce, crust, cheese)) => Pizza(sauce, crust, cheese)
  case Failure(e) => throw e
}
```

The for-comprehension and the `Try` here are just for illustration; a working solution doesn't have to use `for` or `Try`. However, obviously the above syntax is expressive and clean, and *almost* does what I want, so ideally the solution will stick to it as closely as possible.

How can I achieve something like this in Scala?

Comment: The answer is applicative, e.g.
 https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html , someone will probably write the proper full response.

Answer (score 2):

Validated is what you are looking for. It is in Cats for example.

```
import cats.data.Validated
import cats.implicits.catsSyntaxTuple3Semigroupal

def valid(input: String) = if (input.toIntOption.isEmpty) Validated.Invalid(s"$input is not a number")
else Validated.Valid(input.toInt)

def sumThreeNumbers(one:String, two:String, three: String) = (valid(one), valid(two), valid(three)).mapN((oneInt, twoInt, threeInt)=> oneInt + twoInt + threeInt)

sumThreeNumbers("1","2","3")
sumThreeNumbers("1","two","xxx")
//results
val res0: cats.data.Validated[String,Int] = Valid(6)
val res1: cats.data.Validated[String,Int] = Invalid(two is not a number.xxx is not a number.)
```

Comment: Validated is not a monad. It's an applicative functor.

Comment: @Taha you are 100% right! Misleading "monad" removed from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`scala.util.Try` behaves in a fail-fast manner. In a for-comprehension context it executed sequentially and halts at the first failure.

What you need is a structure that aggregates all failures like `cats.data.Validated` or `scalaz.Validation`.

Comment: Scalaz is kinda dead though. ZIO probably has such a type as well.